# Should i use app engine endpoint models in my android application?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I've been trying out google app engine endpoints api as a backend for a new project.
The app engine project is working fine, but i'm struggling to find information 
about how to structure my android application.

I've moved all my data models from the android project over to the app engine project 
for the purpose of creating Endpoints.  However i've created multiple endpoints for the same
entity, for example i've created one searchEndpoint and one personEndpoint for the same model Person.

When I generate client libraries i get multiple Person models in the android application. This means that i can't really use the model in my android application.

So my question is: Is it recommended to use the endpoint models on the client side? Or do i need to create wrapper classes on the backend side and convert them to my own model on the android application.

It seems like the point of using the client libraries over a normal HTTPRequest disappears if i don't use the model classes directly.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this ? I too have to share an entity between multiple endpoints and I see that a different entity is generated for each one. Its so frustrating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would normally have a single endpoint for a model, but that endpoint would have multiple methods (@ApiMethod).  That way, it will only generate a single model for your entity.

In your Android app, you must eventually use the generated model, as that is what is used in the generated endpoint code.  You don't have much control over the generated client model, so you probably won't use it for much other then the endpoints.

Comment: So I should rather create a PersonWrapper entity on the backend side that I use when i communicate with the endpoints? And keep it seperated from my Person class?

Comment: No PersonWrapper, just a single Person entity (in backend) which can be used by any number of ApiMethods in a single endpoint.  Take a look at the sample - I think it is called TicTacToe.  Don't try to actually build and run the sample - Google samples rarely work, they are just for visual inspection.

Comment: I probably should have explained a bit more, but the point of the PersonWrapper was so my Person class could have more functionality on the client side, like helper methods and so forth. And then use the PersonWrapper for the endpoints so i didn't have to limit the Person class to a generated entity class. But I get your point, thanks for the help!